Integrals on Cantor sets
$P$ is a Cantor set. Let
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\ln(1+x^3)  ~~~x\in P\\
x^2  ~~~x\in [0,1]-P
\end{cases}
$$
I want to calculate
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx
$$
What I try: I think the measure of Cantor set is zero, so
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx =\int_0^1 x^2 dx  =\frac{1}{3}
$$
is right?

Yes, it is correct.

This is correct (assuming you are working with the usual Cantor set, which has measure zero, and not a "fat Cantor set" which does not). More broadly, if
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x), & x \in Z \\
h(x), & x \in \Omega \setminus Z
\end{cases}
$$
where

$Z \subseteq \Omega$ is a set of measure zero
$h$ is integrable and defined on all of $\Omega$

then
$$
\int_\Omega f = \int_\Omega h
$$
(You may be able to broaden this further or weaken the conditions, but this is moreso just a generalization of the key statement in the argument.)
